# Why some VPN clients break Java debugging and how to work around the issue?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, remote-debugging, vpn

I am using IntelliJ to develop a Scala project.

Due to client-server architecture of the system, my integration tests have to be run with the following settings in build.sbt:

```
fork in IntegrationTest := true
javaOptions in (IntegrationTest) ++= Seq("-Djdk.logging.allowStackWalkSearch=true", "-XX:PermSize=256M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=512M", "-Xmx1024m")
// for attaching with debugger to the processes under test
javaOptions in (IntegrationTest) += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

Normally everything works fine - tests are being run, debugging works.

Sometimes I need to establish a VPN connection to access some resources of my employee company. I'm using Check Point Endpoint Security VPN (that's the officially recommended software of my employee and I'm not sure if anything else would work).

So, if I happen to be connected to the VPN and then run the integration tests, then SBT console starts getting stuck right after:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

The exact message is:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5025
[error] Uncaught exception when running tests: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last project/it:test for the full output.
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

When I run `last project/it:test` (I have to reload SBT console first because it has stuck in `(busy) >` state) I see this:

```
[debug] javaOptions: List(-Djdk.logging.allowStackWalkSearch=true, -XX:PermSize=256M, -XX:MaxPermSize=512M, -Xmx1024m, -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005)
[debug] Forking tests - parallelism = false
[debug] Create a single-thread test executor
[error] Uncaught exception when running tests: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Sometimes when I disconnect the VPN and run the tests again, it starts working. But often disconnecting VPN doesn't help and I have to reboot my computer.

I have tried some less dramatic solutions - restarting IDE, killing all java and javaw processes, looking at netstat results to see anything still using the port 5005, changing the port to 5025 in build.sbt and reloading SBT console... nothing works, only reboot and only until the next time I need to connect to VPN.

That's a nightmare. I don't want to reboot my machine each time after I connect to VPN.
Is there any solution to this? Any Java flags? Any Windows network stack settings? Any VPN settings?